# Using Paw app with JWT

Tags: jwt, paw-app

I have an API that I've built that uses JWT for authorization. How would I go about generating an appropriate JWT using Paw? I could just write a simple app to take in all my info and spit out a JWT, but I would rather be able to put the info in Paw somehow and have it generate the JWT and send it to the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this was staring me in the face since Paw is so powerful. I just used a dynamic value of my login call that produces the JWT. Now my JWT gets included in my headers automatically. More info can be found here: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Response_Parsed_Body_Dynamic_Value

Comment: This solution saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 7):

You can add an header name `Authorization` and add the `OAuth 2 Autorization` in header value.

Then you need put your token at `Token` - `Bearer` field. (The selected field in the image bellow.)

[image: Paw]

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

Creating an **Authorization** header and adding the string *Bearer* (with a space) before the token as follows:

> Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_TOKEN]

P.S: There's a space between *Bearer* and your token.